# C#'s readonly vs C++'s const - Equivalents

Tags: c#, c++, constants

This is mostly an understanding check, as I couldn't find a complete reference on this topic.

In C#, when I write `readonly Foo myFoo`, I'm essentially saying `myFoo` is a pointer to `Foo`, and the *pointer* cannot be reassigned. To guarantee that the underlying `Foo` can't be reassigned, I need a whole other class or interface `ImmutableFoo`.

Now consider the construct `List<Foo>`. It's basically a pointer to a list of pointers to `Foo`, i.e. similar to `vector<Foo *> *` in C++. There are three places where you could put `const` in C++.

```
const vector<const Foo *> * const
```

- const #1: You cannot modify the vector (by resizing, reassigning elements, etc.)
- const #2: You cannot modify the Foo-s pointed to inside the vector
- const #3: You cannot modify the pointer to the vector

So I think the equivalent of each of these is,

```
List<Foo>               = vector<Foo *> *             // No consts
ReadOnlyCollection<Foo> = const vector<Foo *> *       // First const toggled
List<ImmutableFoo>      = vector<const Foo *> *       // Second const toggled
readonly List<Foo>      = vector<Foo *> * const       // Third const toggled

readonly ReadOnlyCollection<ImmutableFoo>
                        = const vector<const Foo *> * const // All consts toggled
```

Is this table of equivalencies correct?

Comment: const in c++ can also be applied to a class method, a concept that does not exist in C#.  See this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799062/const-methods-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, I think you got it. I think this *const* to *readonly* *translation* is correct, even if you **should not compare those two keywords**. I think there are many other subtly and differently behaves between the C++ *const* and C# *readonly* keyword. Some of them are:

- Const in C++ is more powerful, note that this keyword means a couple
  of different things in different contexts. In many situations using const in C++ is some kind of best practice. In C# we do not use the immutable paradigm that much, but the trend is showing up, if you take a look at [the C# Immutable Collections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn385366(v=vs.110).aspx).
- In C# readonly is not really immutable, as you can still [change readonly Fields/Properties by reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7876333/modify-private-readonly-member-variable).

*tbc...*

Comment: In C++ you can also change consts