# What keywords/tools are there to help the compiler optimise

Tags: c#, .net, code-contracts, compiler-optimization, spec#

Often we're told things like,

> If you're calling a method with a return value that doesn't change, take it out of the loop.

for example when writing code like:

```
for(int i=0; i < Instance.ExpensiveNonChangingMethod(); i++)
{
    // Stuff
}
```

I was wondering if you could some how tell the compiler that given the same inputs (and object instance) you would get the same outputs, so it would know it could move it out of the loop as part of the optimisation process.

Does anything like this exist? Perhaps something like [code-contracts](/questions/tagged/code-contracts) or [spec#](/questions/tagged/spec%23)? Or can they already do this sort of thing?

Is it conceivable that the compiler could reason that a method is a [pure function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) its-self?

**Is there anything I can use in C# that will enable the compiler to perform more optimisation that it otherwise would?** *Yes i'm aware of premature optimisation. I'm asking mostly out of curiosity, but also if something like above did exist it would be 'for free' once the method was marked.*

Comment: Maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592934/pure-functions-in-c

Comment: btw; at the moment the answer is "you; you are the tool that does this" - not meant in the derogatory way, he adds quickly.

Comment: You could potentially make a rewriter that lifts things like this out of the loop, based upon a manual `[Pure]` annotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some efficiency problems are detected by [Microsoft FxCop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476%28VS.80%29.aspx), which is part of the [Platform SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=8279).

The list of 18 performance related issues it detects is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182260%28VS.80%29.aspx).

It does not, however, detect the specific example you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not what you're looking for, but you might be able to rewrite the loop so that the expensive method is only explicitly called once (at the start of the loop):

```
for (int i = Instance.ExpensiveNonChangingMethod();  i-- >= 0; )
{
    // Stuff
}
```

This can also be written as:

```
int i = Instance.ExpensiveNonChangingMethod();
while (i-- >= 0)
{
    // Stuff
}
```

The other obvious approach is to just use a temporary variable (which means doing the optimization yourself):

```
int n = Instance.ExpensiveNonChangingMethod();
for (int i = 0;  i < n;  i++)
{
    // Stuff
}
```